# PYTHON ValueError - how i can change my code so it would bring exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As in the topic. While i give non number value it would not bring up exception but rise error in console. How can i improve my code so it would work as it is intended?

```
def div():
    given = False

    while not given:
        a = int(input("Input first number: "))
        b = int(input("Input second number: "))

        try:
            c = (a / b)
        except ValueError:
            print('Value Error - provide two numbers')
            continue
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Zero Division Error')
            continue
        return f'a/b = {c}'

print(div())
```

Comment: Your error is already happening when you cast your nonnumeric input to int. Either first check if it is numeric, or use try..catch there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are converting the input to an integer outside of the `try` block.
Try (pun intended) moving it into the the `try` block:

```
def div():
    given = False
    while not given:
        try:
            a = int(input("Input first number: "))
            b = int(input("Input second number: "))
            c = (a / b)
        except ValueError:
            print('Value Error - provide a number')
            continue
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Zero Division Error')
            continue
        return f'a/b = {c}'

print(div())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

Add you inputs also in the try block and add a except block for that.

```
def div():
    given = False

    while not given:
    

        try:
            a = int(input("Input first number: "))
            b = int(input("Input second number: "))
            c = (a / b)
        except ValueError:
            print('Value Error - provide two numbers')
            continue
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Zero Division Error')
            continue
        return f'a/b = {c}'

print(div())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the string needs to be numeric. So, you need to assert if the input of the user is numeric before applying `int()`. So, I would just add the `int()` inside the try and it will catch it

```py
def div():
    given = False
    
    while not given:
        a = input("Input first number: ")
        b = input("Input second number: ")

        try:
            c = (int(a) / int(b))
        except ValueError:
            print('Value Error - provide two numbers')
            continue
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Zero Division Error')
            continue
        return f'a/b = {c}'

print(div())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your code and put the `inputs` in the `try/except` blocks. Additionally, you could simply use `while True`:

```
def div():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("Input first number: "))
            b = int(input("Input second number: "))
            c = (a / b)
        except ValueError:
            print('Value Error - provide two numbers')
            continue
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Zero Division Error')
            continue
        return f'a/b = {c}'

print(div())
```

Comment: could you explain why usage of "while True" (and my previous given = False / while not given:) is necessary? i dont really get it.

Comment: @kurdebalans: It is not necessary but follows the same logic and is shorter.

Comment: i understand it is almost the same however i just don't get why i had to code this in the first place? what "while" gives to my code?